# How to link a python file to an html document

Tags: python, html, css

I'm just curious for future reference, how exactly would I link a python program and how would the code be worded to a html document.
Thanks in advance

Comment: _how would the code be worded to a html document_. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*how exactly would I link a python program*"

Comment: Well, for example, I'm making two calculator programs, one inside cmd, the other with its own graphical design (an application).  Wouldn't there be a difference in the way it's worded

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of frameworks you can check out:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

I prefer Django but that's just a personal opinion:

https://www.djangoproject.com/

Frameworks make it easier than ever to build applications and websites. Learn python well, learn how the web works, follow a few tutorials (for example the django tutorial) and you are ready to start developing.

Here is how Django works with templates(html):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

You could use frameworks like [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

i always prefer flask. its simple and light